# mp3 audio metadata upload integration: can I autopopulate title, caption, description from id3 tags?

Tags: plugins, media-library, audio

I'm using the native Wordpress.org Upload New Media subsystem pretty routinely to upload MP3 files. The MP3 file workflow we use populates the ID3 tags with some important user-friendly metadata.

It would be good if the Upload New Media subsystem could populate the title, caption, and description fields for the file in the Media Library automatically.

Has anyone created a Wordpress plugin for that specific purpose?  If so, which one?

If not, is it possible? Any suggestions on how I can proceed to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is [MP3 to Post](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mp3-to-post/) plugin in official repository. It does not integrate with uploader, but it shows how to use [getID3](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/) PHP library to retrieve that information from file.